# What would be the time complexity of min_path_sum_problem without memoization?

Tags: ruby, time-complexity

```rb
def min_path_sum(grid)
  m = grid.length - 1
  n = grid[0].length - 1
  min_path_sum_helper(grid, m, n)
end

def min_path_sum_helper(grid, m, n)
  return grid[0][0] if m == 0 && n == 0
  return Float::INFINITY if m < 0 || n < 0

  left = min_path_sum_helper(grid, m - 1, n)
  right = min_path_sum_helper(grid, m, n - 1)

  [left, right].min + grid[m][n]
end
```

This is the problem on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-path-sum/

I know the time complexity is exponential, but what exactly 2^(N+M) ?

Comment: I think the complexity of this solution is `2^(N*M)`. Because, you will technically visit all the positions of the grid (which is `N*M` in total), and each time you have two options to make (making two calls, one to the above and another to the left).

Comment: Your link should be `https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-path-sum/`.